# PDF => raster, is it possible to adapt the sampling resolution to the input page size?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I am using `convert` (Imagemagick component, delegating to Ghostscript in background) to transform the first page of PDF files to images.

Usually, `convert -density 200 file.pdf[0] first_page.png` will do the job, and it will sample the PDF file at 200 pixels per inch of paper.

However it seldom happens that some PDF are abnormally huge (sometimes A0 paper, and recently a PDF with a page exceeding 23 m² (183 inch in length, 185 in width).

For such files, `convert` will hang, eat CPU time. Images of 35000+ pixels in width and height are simply not usable.

Therefore the question: is there a switch in Imagemagick that would adapt the density to the page size, or at least specify that we don't want to sample more than a portion of maximal area of the PDF file (top left corner, 30x30 inch for example)?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: On its official git repository, [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com) has added the `-w` and `-h` switches that, jointly with `-r` will do what is wanted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified mupdf's pdfdraw to support drawing in best fit mode, so I could state that the output needed to be 128x128 at most and it would fit the output in the box while maintaining the aspect ratio. Before I did that the only way was to use pdfinfo to get the page size and then do the calcuations to fit it in a box and then ask pdfdraw to draw it with that scale factor (dots per inch).

Well, after that long story the process to do that is rather simple:

1. get the page size of the page to render (in pdf terms the media box) this can be done via pdfinfo and grep and will appear in pts (points, 1/72th of an inch) or via a pdf library like pyPDF like:

   ```
   import pyPdf
   p = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file("/home/dan/Desktop/Sieve-JFP.pdf", "rb"))
   x,y,w,h = p.pages[0]['/MediaBox']
   ```
2. for a box fit do `dpi = min( A/(w/72.), B/(h/72.) )`
   where `A` is the maximum width and `B` is the maximum height; `w` and `h` are the width and height of the page.
3. pass `dpi` to `convert -density $dpi`

---

and as requested a slightly fudged git commit diff:

```
commit 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Author: Dan D.
Date:   Thu Jul 28 16:33:33 2011 -0400

    add options to pdfdraw to limit the output's width and height

    note that scaling must occur before rotation

diff --git a/apps/pdfdraw.c b/apps/pdfdraw.c
index 0000000..1234567 100644
--- a/apps/pdfdraw.c
+++ b/apps/pdfdraw.c
@@ -12,8 +12,10 @@
 #endif

 char *output = NULL;
-float resolution = 72;
+float resolution = -1;
 float rotation = 0;
+float width = -1;
+float height = -1;

 int showxml = 0;
 int showtext = 0;
@@ -47,6 +49,8 @@ static void usage(void)
        "\t\tsupported formats: pgm, ppm, pam, png, pbm\n"
        "\t-p -\tpassword\n"
        "\t-r -\tresolution in dpi (default: 72)\n"
+       "\t-w -\tmaximum width (default: no limit)\n"
+       "\t-h -\tmaximum height (default: no limit)\n"
        "\t-A\tdisable accelerated functions\n"
        "\t-a\tsave alpha channel (only pam and png)\n"
        "\t-b -\tnumber of bits of antialiasing (0 to 8)\n"
@@ -150,13 +154,39 @@ static void drawpage(pdf_xref *xref, int pagenum)

    if (output || showmd5 || showtime)
    {
-       float zoom;
+       float zoom = 1.0;
        fz_matrix ctm;
        fz_bbox bbox;
        fz_pixmap *pix;
+       float W, H;

-       zoom = resolution / 72;
-       ctm = fz_translate(0, -page->mediabox.y1);
+       ctm = fz_identity;
+       ctm = fz_concat(ctm, fz_translate(0, -page->mediabox.y1));
+       ctm = fz_concat(ctm, fz_rotate(page->rotate));
+       ctm = fz_concat(ctm, fz_rotate(rotation));
+       bbox = fz_round_rect(fz_transform_rect(ctm, page->mediabox));
+
+       W = bbox.x1 - bbox.x0; 
+       H = bbox.y1 - bbox.y0;
+       if (resolution != -1)
+           zoom = resolution / 72;
+       if (width != -1) 
+       {
+           if (resolution != -1)
+               zoom = MIN(zoom, width/W);
+           else
+               zoom = width/W;
+       }
+       if (height != -1)
+       {
+           if (resolution != -1 || width != -1)
+               zoom = MIN(zoom, height/H);
+           else
+               zoom = height/H;
+       }
+
+       ctm = fz_identity;
+       ctm = fz_concat(ctm, fz_translate(0, -page->mediabox.y1));
        ctm = fz_concat(ctm, fz_scale(zoom, -zoom));
        ctm = fz_concat(ctm, fz_rotate(page->rotate));
        ctm = fz_concat(ctm, fz_rotate(rotation));
@@ -295,7 +325,7 @@ int main(int argc, char **argv)
    fz_error error;
    int c;

-   while ((c = fz_getopt(argc, argv, "o:p:r:R:Aab:dgmtx5")) != -1)
+   while ((c = fz_getopt(argc, argv, "o:p:r:R:w:h:Aab:dgmtx5")) != -1)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
@@ -303,6 +333,8 @@ int main(int argc, char **argv)
        case 'p': password = fz_optarg; break;
        case 'r': resolution = atof(fz_optarg); break;
        case 'R': rotation = atof(fz_optarg); break;
+       case 'w': width = atof(fz_optarg); break;
+       case 'h': height = atof(fz_optarg); break;
        case 'A': accelerate = 0; break;
        case 'a': savealpha = 1; break;
        case 'b': alphabits = atoi(fz_optarg); break;
@@ -321,6 +353,10 @@ int main(int argc, char **argv)
    if (fz_optind == argc)
        usage();

+   if (width+height == -2)
+       if (resolution == -1)
+           resolution = 72;
+
    if (!showtext && !showxml && !showtime && !showmd5 && !output)
    {
        printf("nothing to do\n");
```

Comment: Thank you! When you say you modified pdfdraw… where could I find your modification?

Comment: You're Welcome, well, note that they apply to mupdf's pdfdraw and not to xpdf's pdfdraw which is the command which is most commonly refered to as pdfdraw. They reside in my `~/git.l/mupdf` git repos which is not online. Mainly because my changes apply to an older version of mupdf (I think 0.8; I was going to update for 0.9 but the commits in the mupdf repos are so messy and although the commiters know how to code they don't know how to write git commits) and I am confused about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: is there a way you post a diff anywhere then? Thanks!

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Will try to adapt it! I am considering adding a bounty for that answer when I am able to open it. If I forget please remind me.

Comment: Submitted [patch proposal 692855](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=692855) to Ghostscript. Thanks again.

Comment: Info: MuPDF has added officially `-w` and `-h` that bound the resolution when specified, specify output dimension when resolution is not specified, and `-f` to fit exactly with distortion.

Comment: Note that the semantics of my version's options are different from what was added to mupdf at http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=commit;h=fd6647191a5a34db22355414ab1b2c461587812a

Comment: yes. They however provided the fit option, and best of all they will maintain it over the time. Still thanks for helping me having a good start and a patch to propose.

Comment: Well, I just realized an issue with their code that is solved in my patch. If `page->rotate` is set to a non-zero value, **the output would appear upside down**. And also you must **do scaling before rotation** as in my patch. I had to **recompute the `ctx` after solving for the scaling factor** to solve the issue which is why that code appears twice in my sample.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong command. Use `-resample` instead. It is also advisable to provide a specific width and height if possible.

`-density` is merely a flag. `-resample` actually changes pixel dimensions: the only measurement that matters.

edit:
doc for `-resample`
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resample

> The -density option sets an attribute and does not alter the
>   underlying raster image. It may be used to adjust the rendered size
>   for desktop publishing purposes by adjusting the scale applied to the
>   pixels. To resize the image so that it is the same size at a different
>   resolution, use the -resample option.

At a simplistic level in CG, inches do not exist. For raster images, only the pixels are stored. The dpi is merely a suggestion.

Say you have 3 squares on a table, and 300 pennies. If I have a density of 300 pennies per square, there is only one square with 300 pennies in it.

If I change `density` to 100 pps, I now have 3 squares, but still 300 pennies total (100 pennies in each square). You have not changed the number of pennies, only the manner in which you distribute the pennies across an arbitrary unit of measure.

If I `resample` the original to 100pps I have 1 square, and 100 pennies total. I have changed the number of pennies.

I suspect that in cases where the page size goes up, you are dealing with something that had a high resolution such as 1200dpi line art, and by changing the `density` to 300 quadruples the inch measurement when you open the result with something that honors the flag.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand that answer; could you be more precise and give command line? I recall that I do not know the page dimensions in advance, and I want to make rasters of approximately 200px per inch of paper, unless the output raster would be too large, then downscale. What command would you use for that please? thank you.

Comment: see edit for link to `convert` documentation

Comment: okay, but how does that relate to my problem? PDF format has no notion of pixels when you read it with Imagemagick. When you load it, the `-density` parameter is used to sample it.

Comment: PDF is a container format which can contain images and also contains DPI information for the purposes of rendering a document at the specified paper size. The documentation for `convert` explains what commands and parameters to use. And as I said: if you specify the desired width and or height (aka size), along with the `-resample`, you explicitly tell `convert` what you want. `-resample` command is used to "Resize the image so that its rendered size remains the same as the original at the specified target resolution." Whenever inches are used as a dimension, it is the *rendered size*